# VS Express 2012 in Windows 8.1 - getting Out of memory exception

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, out-of-memory

While running the VS 2012 application, getting an out of memory exception.

This is occuring in debug and release mode and on initial load itself on my development machine.

Even I'm getting the same error on **a new asp.net (default) application**

I already looked at the solutions for similar issues on other threads and none of them worked in this scenario.

Can some one help me on this?

```
 Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:
```

HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9885060
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
       System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +456\

```
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

Comment: Stack traces are useless without accompanying code...

Comment: Ya I agree. The application is a default asp.net application in vs 2012

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated.totally stuck on the development activities

Comment: @Milan - Clearly, it's not a default application, since the .NET Framework version is 4.0 and ASP.NET version is 4.0.  VS 2012 generates Framework 4.5 applications by default, so you seem to have changed something.

Comment: I haven't modified any configurations so far. I created a new ASP.NET web forms application and that is resulting this error.

Comment: Unfortunately the issue was with bad sector on my local machine and it was nothing to do with VS 2012